# Un-understandable behavior for multiprocessing queues

Tags: python

I have two processes as shown here. I omitted the lines that are not relevant to the process:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    syslogd_to_api_q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    api_to_syslogd_q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    log_d_control_q=multiprocessing.Queue()
    my_new_log_demon=multiprocessing.Process(target=log_d.mysyslog_main_operation,args=(syslogd_to_api_q,api_to_syslogd_q,log_d_control_q))
    my_new_log_demon.start()
    my_api_server_process=multiprocessing.Process(target=my_api_server.main_operation,args=(API_to_DN_Q,DN_to_API_Q,api_to_rad_q,rad_to_api_q,api_to_syslogd_q,syslogd_to_api_q,log_d_control_q))
    my_api_server_process.start()
    time.sleep(5)
```

each of the processes functions are written in a separate py file.

I have a third file called "automation.py" that is imported by "my_api_server"
A class called "automation_plane" is written in "automation.py"
An automation_plane object is iniated by the my_api_server.main_operation passing all the queues to the class object
during the class init function:

```
    class object_getter():
         def __init__(self,queue_set):
             self.queue_set=queue_set
    
    #queue_set is a dictionary in the below form:
    # {'process_name':{'busy':#aboolean variable,'write':#includes a queue object for data sent to the target process,'read':#includes a queue object for data to be received from the target process}}
         def send_req_via_q(self,process_name, request_list):
             myoutput = None
             while self.queue_set[process_name]['busy'] == True:
                 time.sleep(0.05)
             self.queue_set[process_name]['busy'] = True
             self.queue_set[process_name]['write'].put(request_list)
             tickels = 0
             while self.queue_set[process_name]['read'].empty() == True and tickels < 100:
                 time.sleep(0.05)
                 tickels = tickels + 1
             if self.queue_set[process_name]['read'].empty() == False: 
                 myobject = self.queue_set[process_name]['read'].get()
                 myoutput = myobject
             self.queue_set[process_name]['busy'] = False
             return myoutput
    
    class automation_plane():
        def __init__(self,queue_set):
            self.object_getter=automation_ops.object_getter(queue_set)
            self.object_getter.send_req_via_q('syslogd',['command1','command1'])
```

later in my code, an endless loop listens to a tcp socket and upon a trigger it calles

```
automation_plane.object_getter.send_req_via_q('syslogd',['command'])
```

error received:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 117, in get
    res = self._recv_bytes()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 217, in recv_bytes
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 141, in _check_closed
    raise OSError("handle is closed")
OSError: handle is closed
```

But when I try to omit calling the automation_plane.object_getter.send_req_via_q('syslogd',['command']) function during  the automation_plane class init function, the issue is resolved!

The is resolved also when using a separate queue in the Q_polling function

Comment: I don't think there's enough to go on here - the useful part of the traceback for your exception has been cut off, we have no idea how you're calling your `polling_q` function (which seems to have become mis-formatted), nor anything about your `my_api_server.main_operation`. Can you give us a [mre] ?

Comment: my_api_server.main_operation has a while True loop reveiving commands from a TCP socket. upon receioving from the socket, a thread is created with  the automation_plane.polling_q() function is being the target.

Comment: `OSError: handle is closed` often occurs when the main-process terminates before the sub-processes finish. Call [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) instead of `time.sleep(5)`.

Comment: ken's suggestion sounds very likely. but _without the code we can't actually answer_, only guess. Please consider editing your question to add the relative code.

Comment: Hello, Ken`s suggestion has given me a hint and actually the think that resolved the issue is to create a new function , call the function that polls the queue then add an endless loop that do nothing just to keep the queue alive. I will edit the post to include code.